# How do I hide "No Instance(s) available" in python?

Tags: python, cmd, wmic

I wrote a script that looks for existing Chrome processes (using wmic) and kills them (with taskkill) before starting a new Chrome instance.

The problem is that on those occasions when there are no running Chrome processes, I get stuck with a cmd window that just says "No Instance(s) Available". It still starts Chrome at the page I want, every single time, I just have that window open and I would like to not have it there.

This is the part that seems to causing the problem (I commented everything else out and ended up with it):

```
import os

def get_wmic():
    wmic = os.popen('wmic process where "name like \'%chrome%\'" get commandline,processid')
    wmic_output = wmic.read()
    wmic.close()
    return wmic_output
```

I tried adding  `>nul`  to the end of the string I send to wmic. It had no effect.

I tried adding  `sys.exit()`  after the close. Didn't help.

I even tried treating it like an exception. That had no effect, either.

How do I get it to either stop showing it or close it if it does show it? Is there a way for python to handle it, or is this strictly on the wmic side of things?

Comment: wrap get_wmic into try - except block with your specific Exception and handle it (you can ignore it using pass in except block

Comment: Thanks :) But, like I said in the original post, I tried treating it like an exception. I did exactly what you said and used a pass in the except block. It didn't stop the window being there. Plus, I'm not even sure it's an exception. I mean, it's not like it kills the code or anything. It goes on fine.

Comment: An error message is written to handle __STDERR__ by `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe` and not to handle __STDOUT__ as the standard output. You would have to append `2>nul` to the command line used inside your Python script to redirect the error message to device __NUL__ to suppress it. See the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: I suggest to read the blog [How to find and list all running processes with Python?](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/10/03/how-to-find-and-list-all-running-processes-with-python/) It would be better to code this task in Python without starting another executable from within Python.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Redirecting the error message makes the message disappear, but still leaves the window there, so it doesn't really solve my problem.

As to using psutils, I'll definitely look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to console using `>CON` and the stderr to device nul `2>nul`

So, if you try it in commandline with this syntax :

```
wmic process where "name like '%chrome%'" get commandline,processid>con 2>nul
```

You will never get this message

> "No Instance(s) Available"